# How can I run ALL my Apps “as administrator” by default in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, administrator, uac

I know that I can change the property in advanced setting of the shortcut to run one app as administrator.
But is possible to do that for all my application? There is a general setting or something somewhere that can tweak that?

Comment: I know it's many years later, but I just found this other question and answers to be helpful: http://superuser.com/questions/1002262/run-applications-as-administrator-by-default-in-windows-10?rq=1

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can disable User Account Control (UAC) entirely from the control panel; this will mean *all* programs (installed, downloaded, background, *everything*) will effectively run with the privileges you currently have to grant manually (via UAC pop-up or compatibility settings).

I *think* this is what you are asking for?

However, **I highly recommend against doing this**; it lowers the security of your entire system by allowing any program to modify your system.

In Windows 7 you can adjust the level of UAC to suit your needs. In descending order of strength, the settings for Win7 are:

- Always notify
  *UAC pop-up for changing certain Windows settings and for programs that require elevated rights.*
- Notify me only when programs try to make changes to my computer
  *Doesn't request permissions when changing Windows settings, they are granted automatically. Programs still require using a UAC pop-up.*
- Notify me only when programs try to make changes to my computer (do not dim my desktop)
  *As above, but screen is not dimmed. Potentially leaving the UAC pop-up windows open to manipulation by other software.*
- **Never notify** (I suspect this is what you are after, but please reconsider!)
  *If logged on as an admin-level user everything is automatically given elevated permissions.*
  *If you are logged on as a standard-level user, anything that requires elevated permissions will automatically be denied (with no opportunity to enter a password in a UAC pop-up).*

Comment: Vista allows notifying without prompting for a password, just asking for permission. Does one of these settings do that in Windows 7?

Comment: @datatoo - all of them (well, except "never notify", for obvious reasons), if you're an admin-level user you just have a allow/deny pop-up to respond to (no need to enter a password). If you're a standard-level user then the UAC pop-up requires an admin-level user to provide a password.

Comment: thanks, I didn't realize that was the cause. It is the safe passwords that make it a hassle when you are a poor typist

Answer (score 6):

1 - Add User To Administrators Group And Remove From Users Group:

1. Log In As Administrator
2. Go To Run ( WinKey + R )
3. Type "control userpasswords2"
4. Select Your Account And Click On "Properties"
5. Select "Group Membership" Tab
6. Select "Administrators"
7. Click OK And OK

---

2 - Disable Approval Mode

1. Log In As Administrator
2. Go To Run ( WinKey + R )
3. Type "secpol.msc"
4. Go To Local Polices > Security Options
5. Find "User Account Control: Switch to the secure desktop when prompting for elevation"
6. Open It Click Disable It And Click Ok.
7. Restart Computer( Very Important Log Off Doesn't Work )

---

Now Every App Will Be Run As Administrator In All Administrator Users

Comment: the info on how to access secpol.msc was very useful

Comment: Thank you this is a godsend. Confirmed that this also works in Win 10

Comment: I recently reinstalled Windows 7 Home. When I try to run `secpol.msc`, the file is not found. I searched for it and found 2 copies, in `c:\Windows\winsxs\amd64_microsoft-windows-s..ytools-ex.resources_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7600.16385_en-us_61a93666a0ac0769\ ` and `c:\Windows\winsxs\amd64_microsoft-windows-s..ment-policytools-ex_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7600.16385_none_b55447455ac6a57a\ ` however running either of them tells me `MMC could not create the snap-in.` ([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUmOF.png)) **Thoughts?**

Answer (score 3):

You can always just logon as the "Administrator" account.

Or, just set UAC to never prompt you, and then all the apps that need admin rights will get it, without you needing to do anything. Just search for "User Account Control" on the Start Menu.

Just so you know though, this is very dangerous. Any malware will have full admin access!

Answer (score 0):

If you are on windows 10 home you can use this to enable the local security policy

https://www.majorgeeks.com/content/page/how_to_enable_local_security_policy_in_windows_10_home.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1108077)