# always run programs as administrator in Windows 10

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, user-accounts, process, uac

The title is a bit misleading, but I cannot think of a better one. See the following example to explain what I want:

- Under Windows 7, the current User I am using is a "Computer Administrator" account. After updating to Windows 10, the account type of my current User is still "Administrator".
- Let's say I want to edit the `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` file.
- Typically I just use the Windows Explorer, navigate to that path and then right click on the `hosts` file and choose, in my case `Edit with Sublime Text 2` - since I have Sublime Text 2 installed and I prefer to use that for editing any text file.
- This works fine under Windows XP and Windows 7 (with UAC disabled). However, after updating to Windows 10 (also with UAC disabled), the Sublime Text process will not have enough rights to save that file.

So my question is: what is the difference here between Windows 7 and Windows 10? Why is a process, that is not run under the Administrator account under Windows 7 able to write to that location, but under Windows 10 it is not? Even though the account used in both cases is of type "Administrator?"

Comment: By *with UAC disabled* you mean *do not notify* option in control panel? Starting from Windows 8 this option does not disable UAC, as immersive apps can not work with UAC disabled.

Comment: Yes, I mean _Never Notify_ (which is still the same setting as in Windows 7; I did not know that it cannot be disabled in general).

Comment: Starting from Windows 8 *Never Notify* mean auto approve mode, where elevation requests are approved without asking user, but application still need to request elevation to get full admin rights.

Answer (score 4):

As @PetSerAl pointed out, setting UAC to *Never Notify* only enables the "administrator in Admin Approval Mode" user type while disabling all other User Account Control (UAC) policies.

To disable UAC completely, the `EnableLUA` property of

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System
```

in the registry needs to be changed to `0`. This disables the "administrator in Admin Approval Mode" user type, thus allowing all administrator users to run their processes as administrators by default.

See also https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc232765.aspx

Comment: Meh, I knew that with this change any Store Apps would not work. However, even simple Apps like the Calculator won't work anymore...