# Visual Studio 2017 Open Files from Explorer/Desktop Doesn't Open File Correctly

Tags: visual-studio

I have a fresh install of VS2017. I've set it to always run as Administrator. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9654833/how-to-run-visual-studio-as-administrator-by-default)

I want to open XML files from my desktop and edit in VS. I've right clicked on the XML file and choose Open with Visual Studio 2017.

VS2017 opens, but the XML file is never loaded in. It simply opens VS to a blank screen.

Obviously I would expect the file to actually open. Not sure what could be going on here.

Comment: I've confirmed that marking DEVENV to run as Administrator always via Trouble Shooting is what is causing this. Removing forced Administrator rights allows files to open properly. Is there a different way I should be forcing Administrator rights? Not sure why Admin would cause this behavior.

Comment: I've always ran VS as Admin. Have had problems in the past in not doing so. Hence why there are so many people up-voting an commenting on that thread.

Comment: From the question I posted above

Comment: Fair enough I still find it odd (bug) when running as Admin files don't open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all comes down to the way you configure Visual Studio to be executed (as administrator or normally): I imagine you want Visual Studio to run as administrator in order to attach to processes, but while simply opening an *.XML file, Visual Studio can open normally.

Therefore I advise you to modify the Visual Studio shortcut (shortcut properties, Shortcut, Advanced, Run as administrator), but don't do the troubleshooting, mentioned in the URL.

Comment: This makes sense. It's just annoying to have to open VS from Shortcut first before open an SLN file. I want to just open an SLN and have it run as Administrator from the go.

Comment: Did you already check this post: "https://superuser.com/questions/1002262/run-applications-as-administrator-by-default-in-windows-10"?