# Everything is running with administrator privileges-- how do I explicitly run something as a user?

Tags: windows, windows-10, administrator, group-policy, uac

This is on a domain-attached workstation on which I have local admin access. I'm not sure if our IT department set a GPO or something, but every single program I launch-- regardless of whether I double-click it, choose "Run as Administrator" from context menu, "Open" from context menu, or launching by opening an associated file-- runs as Administrator.

This is handy for some things. I like always launching PowerShell and Visual Studio as admin. But some installers that are meant to install only to my local user profile, like VS Code, are still launching as Admin. That's not good.

My UAC controls are set to "Never Notify," but changing it to any other setting above that does not change the behavior.

How can I switch this off? I only want to launch certain programs consistently as admin-- not everything.

Thanks.

Details:

- Windows 10 Enterprise
- 1909 Build 18363.1082 64-bit

Comment: How have you determine a process is being ran as an Administrator exactly?

Comment: You should talk to your active domain Administrator for assistance

Comment: cmd.exe and PowerShell show "Administrator: {program name}" in the title bar. Visual Studio Code installer warns not to run it as admin.

Comment: I also checked my local group policy per this answer here (https://superuser.com/questions/1002262/run-applications-as-administrator-by-default-in-windows-10/1002306#1002306) but everything is set to the opposite, meaning it should be prompting me for elevation. But it's not.

Comment: "My UAC controls are set to "Never Notify"  <-- This will override and should be turned off

Comment: Please see the rest of that sentence-- changing it to the other options does not change the behavior. And local policy seems to indicate that I should be prompted.

Comment: Change the Group Policy for this machine / this user (you). My answer describes how my setup works very well at all my clients.

Comment: **This question should include more details and clarify the problem.** Please **edit** your question to provide the necessary information to answer your question.  The lack of a UAC prompt doesn’t mean your applications are always being ran as an elevated process.  It just means your not prompted for explicit permission.

Comment: I have said explicitly multiple times that my processes are definitely being launched with elevated privileges. Visual Studio and PowerShell both clearly indicate when they are launched in admin mode. There's no UAC prompt, the UAC prompt level is set to "Notify," and the processes are still running as admin. Local policy is also set to prompt for elevation, as also noted. I'm not sure what other details I can provide. Could it be a corrupted profile?

Answer (score 0):

If you are Local Admin, then you can run all programs. If they need admin credentials, OK will do it.

For UAC Controls, set for popping up and NOT Never.  Never means never stop what you are doing.  Go into Settings, type UAC in the search box and change the settings.

Once you do this, some programs (not all) will challenge you to start as Admin and you can say Yes (OK) or NO.  If you run this way, then the app will run as admin.

If you need to run as a Standard User to see what a User can do, make a new Standard User profile and log in that way.

You cannot be a true Standard User in an Admin Account.

Comment: Thanks, but I indicated in my question that changing the UAC account controls does nothing to stop this behavior. Group Policy also indicates that I should be prompted for elevation. It's my understanding that, except for the default Administrator account, all accounts are standard users that have the _ability_ to elevate commands if they're in the Administrators group.

Comment: Once UAC is running, your Admin Account will run programs without much restraint, only stopping you to get started. As I pointed out, true Standard User experience needs a different User Account.