# How can I run ALL my Apps “as administrator” in windows 10

Tags: windows-10, permissions, uac

I know about the suggestions of http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/3436-run-administrator-windows-10-a.html. However not one option provides an answer to my question. I want to run as admin **all** applications without executing an action for each one of them.

Comment: Maybe set UAC to the minimum security level? I know there's a command for it, but it could leave a big security gap in Windows. I'll report back if I find the command...

Comment: This may also help: [204781](http://superuser.com/questions/204781/how-can-i-run-all-my-apps-as-administrator-by-default-in-windows-7).

Comment: why my question is duplicate? where is the reference to double?

Answer (score -2):

Run Powershell as admin:

run: Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System" -Name "EnableLUA" -Value "0"

restart PC

Comment: This **would not**  elevate a process to an Administrator.  This just disabled the UAC prompt.  Did you try your suggestion before you made it?